# Highlight search pattern without moving cursor

Tags: vim

In vim, is it possible to highlight a search pattern without moving the cursor?

For example, if I want to find `m_depthTable` I could do:

```
/m_depthTable
```

and that will highlight all instances of `m_depthTable`, but it will also move to the next occurance.

I want to highlight without moving.  Possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do a substitute command with the n flag. This won't move the cursor or do the substitute.

```
:s/pattern//n
```

Comment: We might have a winner here.

Comment: ha, I knew `n` flag, but didn't think of this way. nice..+1 your answer.  but I would press the backs-tick twice, if I need do this.

Answer (score 7):

just

```
/pattern<enter>
```

then press <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>

Comment: OK, well it does move the cursor but then it moves it back.  I guess that works.

Comment: @JohnDibling if you need this very often, you could create mapping, function.. then you don't feel its moving.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can write directly into register that contains last search pattern:

```
:let @/="m_depthTable"
```

Comment: Just checked. It does.

Comment: Didn't highlight for me, sorry.

Comment: it does there, because you have already searched and highlighted something. try `:noh` then set the `@/`.

Comment: @Kent, checked once again. You're right! Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @black_wizard no problem... just last month,  I had the same thought too. ;)